# Sort array on one variable that can hold multiple values

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

How can I sort an array of `Accounts` that need to be sorted on an array of `PersonRoles` that say which role an associated person has with that account?

For example,

Bob is the Owner (`O`) of account `12`, the Co-signer (`CO`) of account `123`, and the Beneficiary of account `1234`.

Joe is the Owner (`O`) of account `123` and account `1234` the Beneficiary (`BE`) of account `12`.

How would I sort the array of `Accounts` **for Bob** in the order of Owners (`O`) first, then Co-signer('CO'), then Beneficiary (`BE`) in that order.

Accounts object structure

```
Accounts
{
    AccountNumber: 12,
    PersonRoles: [
                     {
                         AccountRoleCode: "O",
                         AccountRoleDescription: "Owner",
                         Person: "Bob"
                     },
                     {
                         AccountRoleCode: "CO",
                         AccountRoleDescription: "Co-Signer",
                         Person: ""
                     },
                     {
                         AccountRoleCode: "BE",
                         AccountRoleDescription: "Beneficiary",
                         Person: "Joe"
                     },
                 ],
    Balance: 5.00
},
{
    AccountNumber: 123,
    PersonRoles: [
                     {
                         AccountRoleCode: "O",
                         AccountRoleDescription: "Owner",
                         Person: "Joe"
                     },
                     {
                         AccountRoleCode: "CO",
                         AccountRoleDescription: "Co-Signer",
                         Person: "Bob"
                     },
                     {
                         AccountRoleCode: "BE",
                         AccountRoleDescription: "Beneficiary",
                         Person: null
                     },
                 ],
    Balance: 100.00
},
{
    AccountNumber: 1234,
    PersonRoles: [
                     {
                         AccountRoleCode: "O",
                         AccountRoleDescription: "Owner",
                         Person: "Joe"
                     },
                     {
                         AccountRoleCode: "CO",
                         AccountRoleDescription: "Co-Signer",
                         Person: null
                     },
                     {
                         AccountRoleCode: "BE",
                         AccountRoleDescription: "Beneficiary",
                         Person: "Bob"
                     },
                 ],
    Balance: 10000000.00
}
```

Original array of Accounts listed under Bob returned from API.

`[1234, 12, 123]`

Desired Sorted array.

`[12, 123, 1234]`

My initial approach is to use LINQ on the array, but I'm unsure how to loop through the `Accounts[]` and then loop through the `PersonRoles[]` to sort the `Accounts[]` based on the `PersonRoles[]`.

Does this need like a double LINQ query? Or would another approach be better?

Comment: Use Array.Sort(Array,IComparer ): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AccountsByNameComparer : IComparer<Account>
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public AccountsByNameComparer(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public int Compare(Account x, Account y)
    {
        return AccountSortValue(x).CompareTo(AccountSortValue(y));
    }

    private int AccountSortValue(Account account)
    {
        if (account.PersonRoles.Any(role => role.AccountRoleCode == "O"
                                            && role.Name == _name)) return 0;
        if (account.PersonRoles.Any(role => role.AccountRoleCode == "CO"
                                            && role.Name == _name)) return 1;
        if (account.PersonRoles.Any(role => role.AccountRoleCode == "BE"
                                            && role.Name == _name)) return 2;
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
accounts.Sort(new AccountsByNameComparer("Bob"));
```

or

```
var sorted = accounts.OrderBy(a => a, new AccountsByNameComparer("Bob"));
```

The benefits of this are

- You can unit test the comparer
- You can have different comparers for the same class, in case in some other context you want to sort differently
- Putting it in a separate class ensures that you won't duplicate code if you find yourself needing the same sorting in multiple places.

This is a regrettably long and convoluted unit test. But you have to verify that it works somehow, and this is usually easier than actually running the whole application.

```
[TestClass]
public class SortAccountsByNameTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AccountsAreSortedInCorrectOrder()
    {
        var account1 = new Account
        {
            PersonRoles = new PersonRole[]
            {
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "BE", Name = "Bob"},
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "CO", Name = "Steve"},
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "O", Name = "John"},
            }
        };
        var account2 = new Account
        {
            PersonRoles = new PersonRole[]
            {
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "CO", Name = "Bob"},
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "O", Name = "Steve"},
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "BE", Name = "John"},
            }
        };
        var account3 = new Account
        {
            PersonRoles = new PersonRole[]
            {
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "O", Name = "Bob"},
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "CO", Name = "Steve"},
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "BE", Name = "John"},
            }
        };
        var account4 = new Account
        {
            PersonRoles = new PersonRole[]
            {
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "O", Name = "Al"},
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "CO", Name = "Steve"},
                new PersonRole {AccountRoleCode = "BE", Name = "John"},
            }
        };
        var unsorted = new Account[] {account1, account2, account3, account4};
        var comparer = new AccountsByNameComparer("Bob");
        var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(a => a, comparer);
        var expectedOrder = new Account[]{account3, account2, account1, account4};
        Assert.IsTrue(expectedOrder.SequenceEqual(sorted));
    }
}
```

I'm going to get carried away now. What if you want to change the order in which you sort these without rewriting the entire comparer? Or you just don't like those `if` statements? (Sorry, this is obnoxious and useless. Why am I doing this?)

```
public class AccountsByNameComparer : IComparer<Account>
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly List<string> _preferredRoleSequence;

    public AccountsByNameComparer(string name, IEnumerable<string> preferredRoleSequence)
    {
        _name = name;
        _preferredRoleSequence = preferredRoleSequence.ToList();
    }

    public int Compare(Account x, Account y)
    {
        return AccountSortValue(x).CompareTo(AccountSortValue(y));
    }

    private int AccountSortValue(Account account)
    {
        var rolesMatchedByName = account.PersonRoles
            .Where(role => role.Name == _name);
        var preferredRoleMatches =
            rolesMatchedByName.Select(role => 
                _preferredRoleSequence.IndexOf(role.AccountRoleCode))
                    .Where(index => index > -1)
                    .ToArray();
        if (preferredRoleMatches.Any())
            return preferredRoleMatches.Min();
        return Int32.MaxValue;
    }
}

public class ExecutiveAccountsByNameComparer : AccountsByNameComparer
{
   public ExecutiveAccountsByNameComparer(string name)
        :base(name, new []{"O", "CO", "BE" }) { }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
    var result = accounts
        .Select(a => new
        {
            a.AccountNumber,
            RoleCodes = a.PersonRoles
                .Where(r => r.Person == "Bob")
                .Select(r => r.AccountRoleCode)
                .ToArray(),
        })
        .OrderBy(a => a.RoleCodes.Select(code => GetOrderByCode(code)).Max())
        .ThenBy(a => a.AccountNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, assuming Bob has one and only one role in all accounts:

```
var ordered = 
    from a in Accounts
    from r in a.PersonRoles 
    where r.Person == "Bob" 
    let ordering = r.AccountRoleCode == "O" ? 1 : r.AccountRoleCode == "CO" ? 2 : 3
    orderby ordering
    select a.AccountNumber;
```

Variation, if Bob can have multiple roles (and Bob has a role in every account). In this case, we first select the right role, the first one in the order specified:

```
var ordered = 
    from a in Accounts
    let bobsrole = (
        from r in a.PersonRoles
        where r.Person == "Bob"
        let o = r.AccountRoleCode == "O" ? 1 : r.AccountRoleCode == "CO" ? 2 : 3
        orderby o
        select (rolename: r,ordering: o)
    ).First()
    orderby bobsrole.ordering
    select a.AccountNumber;
```

Excercise for the reader: what if there are accounts where Bob is not involved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Linq statement like this:

```
var givenPerson = "Bob";
Accounts.Where(a => a.PersonRoles.SelectMany(r => r.Person).Contains(givenPerson))
    .OrderBy(a => a, new CustomComparerForRoleCode(givenPerson));
```

To do a custom compare to sort by the `AccountRoleCode`, you'll need a comparer class:

```
public class CustomComparerForRoleCode : IComparer<PersonRole[]>
{
    public string PersonInRole { get; set; }

    public CustomComparerForRoleCode(string personInRole) {
        this.PersonInRole = personInRole;
    }

    public int Compare(PersonRole[] x, PersonRole[] y) {
        var roleCode = x.First(r => r.Person == PersonInRole).AccountRoleCode;
        var otherRoleCode = y.First(r => r.Person == PersonInRole).AccountRoleCode;
        if (roleCode == otherRoleCode)
            return 0;
        switch (roleCode) {
            case "O":
                return 1;
            case "BE":
                return -1;
            case "CO":
                if (otherRoleCode == "O")
                    return -1;
                return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes a person can have only one role per account.  Adjust as needed.